# Rename tab from "first" in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with two tabs after I used "File > New > Project > Tabbed Application". For the life of me, I can't figure out how to edit the caption shown on the tabs. I want the first tab to show up as "Feed" and the second tab should be named "Options"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the right of your view controller where you can see two more controller

You can select the first scene and change the Title of tabbar item to 'Feed' instead of first as shown in the image 
[image]

Same will be for second item: Select second scene follow the same steps you will get another tabbaritem select it and change the Title to Options from the second